# How to define bind operator using type class?

Tags: haskell, set, monads

### How to define bind operator using type class?

I want to define monad instance to a type.
Below is the source code I wrote.

```
data Set a = Eq a => Set [a]

newtype SetMonad a = SetMonad {unMonad :: Set a}

instance Functor SetMonad

instance Applicative SetMonad

-- Implemention of Monad instance for "SetMonad"
instance Monad SetMonad where
  (>>=) :: SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
  (SetMonad v) >>= f = SetMonad $ fromList $ concat $ elems $ unMonad $ mapM f (elems v)

-- utils for "Set a"

elems :: Set a -> [a]
elems (Set a) = a

fromList :: Eq a => [a] -> Set a
fromList [] = Set []
fromList (x : xs) = fromList' [] (x : xs)
  where
    fromList' [] (x : xs) = fromList' [x] xs
    fromList' ys (x : xs) = if x `elem` ys then fromList' (x : ys) xs else fromList' ys xs
    fromList' ys [] = Set ys
```

Actually, this code has a compile error.

```
• No instance for (Eq b) arising from a use of ‘fromList’
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq b) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        (>>=) :: forall a b. SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘fromList d’
  In the expression: SetMonad $ fromList d
  In the expression:
    let d = concat $ elems $ unMonad $ mapM f (elems v)
    in SetMonad $ fromList dtypecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
```

bind operator's type is defined in the other package (Control.Monad) and I cannot override this (compile error occurs.)
but I need to use (==) operator in the implemention of (>>=).
how should I fix it?

### What I tried

- Tried to change the type defination of bind operator.

```
instance Monad SetMonad where
  (>>=) :: Eq a => SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
  (SetMonad v) >>= f = SetMonad $ fromList $ concat $ elems $ unMonad $ mapM f (elems v)
```

and caused compile errors:

```
• No instance for (Eq a)
    arising from the check that an instance signature is more general
    than the type of the method (instantiated for this instance)
    instance signature:
      >>= :: forall a b.
             Eq a =>
             SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
    instantiated method type:
      forall a b. SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        (>>=) :: forall a b. SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
• When checking that instance signature for ‘>>=’
    is more general than its signature in the class
    Instance sig: forall a b.
                  Eq a =>
                  SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
       Class sig: forall a b.
                  SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
  In the instance declaration for ‘Monad SetMonad’
```

```
• Could not deduce (Eq b) arising from a use of ‘fromList’
  from the context: Eq a
    bound by the type signature for:
               (>>=) :: forall a b.
                        Eq a =>
                        SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
    at /home/txjp/dev/drive2/src/Sandbox2.hs:127:12-64
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq b) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        (>>=) :: forall a b.
                 Eq a =>
                 SetMonad a -> (a -> SetMonad b) -> SetMonad b
• In the first argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘fromList’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘fromList $ concat $ elems $ unMonad $ mapM f (elems v)’
  In the expression:
    SetMonad $ fromList $ concat $ elems $ unMonad $ mapM f (elems v)
```

### Background

List monad is usiful for nondeterministic computation.
but sometimes unfavorable because it has the idea of order when I interested only in combinations.
So, I wanted to implement list-like monad which have no concept of order.

Normally, I should use Data.Set package, but it need to be Ord instance to use.
so, I used a list-based implemention to make things easier.

Please give me some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known conumdrum](https://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/set-monad.html). There are hacks to get this working, but IMO the issue is ultimately that sets just don't make sense as monads in the **Hask** category.

They *do* make sense as monads in the subcategory of types with an `Eq` instance. This is the kind of thing that I wrote the [`constrained-category` package for](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0). <sub>(There are many alternatives: [`data-category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category), [`constrained-monads`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-monads), [`constrained`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained), [`subhask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/subhask)...)</sub>. The idea is to restrict all mapping so you always stay within the class of allowed types. You don't really need to include the `Eq` constraint in the type then, this mostly just complicates things.

```
import qualified Prelude as Hask

import Control.Category.Constrained
import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude

import Data.List (nub)

newtype Set a = Set { setElems :: [a] }

instance Eq a => Eq (Set a) where
  (==) = ... -- beware that order should not matter

fromList :: Eq a => [a] -> Set a
fromList = Set . nub

instance Functor Set (Eq ⊢ (->)) (Eq ⊢ (->)) where
  fmap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism
           $ \(Set s) -> fromList $ map f s

instance Monoidal Set (Eq⊢(->)) (Eq⊢(->)) where
  pureUnit = ConstrainedMorphism pure
  fzipWith (ConstrainedMorphism f)
    = ConstrainedMorphism $ \(Set xs, Set ys)
        -> Set . fromList $ fzipWith f (xs,ys)
instance Applicative Set (Eq ⊢ (->)) (Eq ⊢ (->)) where
  pure = ConstrainedMorphism pure

instance Monad Set (Eq ⊢ (->)) where
  join (Set s) = fromList $ s >>= setElems
```

Comment: Wow. That's a *lot* of newtype noise for the amount of actual code. I understand why, but it is definitely a bummer.